# Passing a string representing date to postgres query in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

Trying to execute this postgres query:

```
select date('2015-10-05') from posts;
```

I'm passing the date as a string:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(
  Repo, "select date('$1') from posts", ["2015-10-05"])
```

But getting an error that the datetime format is invalid.

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (invalid_datetime_format): 
  invalid input syntax for type date: "$1"

[debug] select date('$1') from posts ["2015-10-05"]
  ERROR query=0.6ms
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:172: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/5
```

However, I'm not passing it as a date, but as a string. Postgres' `date()` function accepts string too, AFAIK and the error is still the same when I add `::varchar` to make sure it's a string. Any advice how can this be avoided?

Comment: Since there's an Ecto.Date primitive (https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Date.html) what happens when you try that?

Comment: What happens when you do the query directly in the postgres cli, `psql`?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci it works too, thanks!

Comment: @PatrickOscity if you mean, how does it work with substitution e.g. when `2015-10-05` is provided via arguments, I'm not sure how such query would look like. But otherwise it simply makes a query that selects the same date for all the posts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want to pass it into Ecto in the form `{2015, 10, 5}` instead of as a string.

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(Repo, "SELECT $1::date", [{2015, 10, 5}])
```

You can make a little helper function to turn a string into that format:

```
def string_to_date(str) do
  {_, date} = Ecto.Date.cast(str)
  Ecto.Date.to_erl(date)
end
```